# Access part of array of object based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I want to access names from this data whose status is completed how do it do that?
I have fetched this data from an API and I want to save the names into a state whose status is completed.

```js
"data": [
  {
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "_id": "606bf5d19173931121c0017c",
    "userId": {
      "_id": "606bf5d19173931121c0017a",
      "email": "admin1@gmail.com",
      "contactNumber": 7896541236
    },
    "name": "Admin1"
  },
  {
    "status": "PENDING",
    "_id": "606c074e9173931121c0017f",
    "userId": {
      "_id": "606c074e9173931121c0017d",
      "email": "admin3@gmail.com",
      "contactNumber": 9638527416
    },
    "name": "Admin3"
  },
  {
    "status": "PENDING",
    "_id": "606c07a99173931121c00182",
    "userId": {
      "_id": "606c07a99173931121c00180",
      "email": "admin4@gmail.com",
      "contactNumber": 9638527477
    },
    "name": "Admin4"
  },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looking at this it seems it would be a straight forward `reduce` no?

Comment: I don't how to approach this so yeah i haven't tried i guess.

Comment: Have a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an array. Arrays have different methods (functions) you can run. These allow you to find items or update the array. In this case `filter`, `find` or `findIndex` seem like a good fit. To learn more about Arrays see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

#### filter()

`filter()` will return an array of items that match your condition, in this case:

`data.filter(item => item.status === "COMPLETED")`

#### find()

Alternative, `find` will return the first item that matches your condition:

`data.find(item => item.status === "COMPLETED")`

#### findIndex()

`findIndex` is similar to `find`, but it returns the index instead of the actual item:

`data.findIndex(item => item.status === "COMPLETED")`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to filter data with completed status. It will filter all data with status equals to completed and then map their name to completedNames.

```
const completedNames=data.filter(people => people['status']==='COMPLETED').map(person => person['name'])
```

Also if you are using functional component you can use useState to assign this to a state:

```
import {useState} from 'React'

const [compNames, setCompNames] = useState([]);

.
.
const completedNames=data.filter(people => people['status']==='COMPLETED').map(person => person['name'])

setCompNames(completedNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `filter` will be a good option when filtering a data stack, for cases like this. But here are a few options you can go with;

```
var data = []

data = json.data.filter(d => d.status == 'COMPLETED')
console.log(data)

data = []
json.data.reduce(d => d.status == 'COMPLETED' && data.push(d))
console.log(data)

data = []
json.data.forEach(d => d.status == 'COMPLETED' && data.push(d))
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a few other answers have pointed out, `filter()` provides an effective way of only retrieving those items from the `data` returned by your API that match the `completed` status, and then return the names from those items using `map()`.

Here it is in action. Click "Run code snippet" below to see the result(s):

```js
const data = [{ status: "COMPLETED", _id: "606bf5d19173931121c0017c", userId: { _id: "606bf5d19173931121c0017a", email: "admin1@gmail.com", contactNumber: 7896541236 }, name: "Admin1" }, { status: "PENDING", _id: "606c074e9173931121c0017f", userId: { _id: "606c074e9173931121c0017d", email: "admin3@gmail.com", contactNumber: 9638527416 }, name: "Admin3" }, { status: "PENDING", _id: "606c07a99173931121c00182", userId: { _id: "606c07a99173931121c00180", email: "admin4@gmail.com", contactNumber: 9638527477 }, name: "Admin4" }, ];

// if you want a filtered list of ALL details
let filteredData = data.filter(e => e.status === "COMPLETED");
console.log('filteredData =', filteredData);

// if you want a filtered list of ONLY names
let filteredNames = data.filter(e => e.status === "COMPLETED").map(e => e.name);
console.log('filteredNames =', filteredNames);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0 !important; max-height: 100% !important } .as-console-row::after { display: none !important } .as-console-row code { display: block; border-width: 1px 0 0 0 !important }

.as-console { counter-reset: section; }
.as-console-row {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  position: relative;
}
.as-console-row::before {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  z-index; 900;
}
```